# With the local Cauchy Integral formula find $\int_{|z-2|=2}\frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{z^2-1}dz$ and $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{(z+1)^2}dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> With the assistance of the local Cauchy Integral formula find the values of:
>
> (i) $\displaystyle\int_{|z-2|=2}(z^2-1)^{-1}\tan^{-1}(z)dz$;
>
> (ii)$\displaystyle\int_{|z|=2}(z+1)^{-2}e^zdz$.

I tried to solve these two integrals, the first one I do not know if I solved it well and the second one I do not know how to solve it, could someone help me please? Thank you very much, here is my attempt to solve (i):
\begin{align}
\int_{|z-2|=2}(z^2-1)^{-1}\tan^{-1}(z)dz
&= \int_{|z-2|=2}\frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{z^2-1}dz \\
&= \int_{|z-2|=2}\frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{2(z-1)}-\frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{2(z+1)}dz \\
&= \int_{|z-2|=2}\frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{2(z-1)}dz \\
&= \frac{1}{2}2\pi i\tan^{-1}(1) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi^2i}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok. The first calculation looks correct. For the second one, use Cauchy's differentiation formula.

Comment: @kobe Cauchy's differentiation formula? What is that formula?

Comment: $$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{c} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\, dz$$